# View which manages some generic variable object with Prism

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm working with Prism and I have a view which will manage some variable entity objects.

E.g.: Now I'm managing a `User`, but later I would manage a `Customer` using the same view (I already have the solution to achieve it ... [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8987709/1148768) - [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945930/1148768)).

This object (or the object type) to be managed must be declared and passed by me.

In a common way, I could pass the object type through a parameter on the constructor, but as I'm using Prism and I don't directly use the constructor of the Views or ViewModels.

Here's a snippet of how I currently "invoke" my views:

```
var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
var viewUri = new Uri("MyGenericView", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("AreaTrabalho", viewUri);
```

The problem is: I can't pass a parameter. Is there a way of passing that parameter or an alternative way of doing this (without a kind of ugly hack)?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `INavigationAware` on your VM's and pass parameters inside query string in your `regionManager.RequestNavigate` call

Comment: Implementing `INavigationAware` on my ViewModels didn't work for me. It only worked when implemented on the Views. And as far as I know, I can only pass `string` through a query string.