# MVVM Execute Command on ViewModel from other ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm struggling for about 14 days now with a simple task: In database, I have definitions for hardware categories. For example :

1. HDD

   - Internal
   - External
   - Flash

This list is in database defined like this:

```
    [ID - ParrentID - Name] : 1 - 0 - HDD, 2 - 1 - Internal, 3 - 1 - External, 4 - 1 - Flash.
```

Through Entity Framework I get these rows into my application. From this flat data I then create structured object which is my DataModel. This model is defined as follows :

```
public class Category
{
   private int _id = -1;
   private string _name = "";
   private List<Category> _subCategories = null;
// property getters and setters, constructors, and bool HasSubCategories
}
```

Now, from these I create ViewModel called *SubCategoryViewModel* to which is binded my TreeView. So, I can view my categories in treeview and with my defined and maintained hierarchy. This works just fine. In *SubCategoryViewModel* is defined a **Command** through *Attached Behavior for MouseDoubleClick* which is also binded to TreeView. So, when user doubleclicks on Item, in *SubViewCategoryModel* defined method will execute particular code. List of  *SubCategoryViewModel* is nested in *HWDocumentViewModel* which is a main ViewModel for my window. 
What I need now is obvious : When user doubleclicks on item in TreeView, I need to load items from database and show them in ListView. My opinion is, that in *HWDocumentViewModel* I need to define an collection of Items and load them accordingly to selected category in ListView. But, I don't know how to execute a method on HWDocumentViewModel from *SubCategoryViewModel*. Because : TreeView is binded to list of *SubCategoryViewModel* items, so when DoubleClick occurs, the method on *SubCategoryViewModel* is executed. I'm searching for a way, how to execute a method on main ViewModel (HWDocumentViewModel).

I tried this approach :
I created a property : `public static SubCategoryViewModel SelectedCategory` on  `HWDocumentViewModel`. When doubleclick occurs, I set this property from SubCategoryViewModel as `this`. So, in this property is object, which executed doubleclick event delegate. Great, now I have in HWDocumentView model an object, which user selected.
So, I need to load items to ListView. But, will I load them from method in *SubCategoryViewModel* ? I don't think so. Instead I should load them from Main View Model  by creating a ViewModel for them and bind it to ListView, right ? But, how can I from SubCategoryViewModel call a method in HWDocumentViewModel ? Should I write a static method
on a HWDocumentViewModel which will be accessible from SubCategoryViewModel ?
**Or is there a way, how to call Command defined on HWDocumentViewModel from SubCategoryViewModel ?**

Or generally, did I take a right approach to create a Warehouse-like application in WPF ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: XAML for my TreeView looks like this :

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvCategories" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                            <Setter Property="behaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"  Value="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" />
                            <Setter Property="behaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localvm:SubCategoryViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.Resources>

                </TreeView>
```

Comment: Can you add your treeview xaml please. Your question is giving me allot of confusion regarding the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the problem. You have a tree of subcategories and when one is selected, the appropriate `SubCategoryViewModel` sets itself as `SelectedCategory` on the main `HWDocumentViewModel`. That seems like a reasonable approach.

So why do you need to call a command? Why can't you just load the new list in `HWDocumentViewModel` in response to a change of its `SelectedCategory` property (ie in the setter)?

If you really must use a command to invoke the load, then simply keep a reference to your main `HWDocumentViewModel` in each `SubCategoryViewModel`, and invoke the command with a simple:

```
_mainViewModel.LoadCategoryCommand.Execute();
```

Comment: This is the solution, which I wanted. But I'm a bit confused - the approach which I took, you're saying that it is reasonable - i.e. Have a static property on main view model and set it by other view model. Is it a true MVVM way ?

Comment: Well, not static no. But a normal property is fine IMO. You could use events to decouple the view models but that seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 3):

With MVVM and trying to communicate between View and ViewModel or between ViewModels a publisher/Subscriber setup works well or a messaging paradigm like what's found in MVVMLight or Prism. I posted an answer on MVVM Light's messaging setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304581/let-the-viewmodel-know-the-generic-object-of-the-view/9318439#9318439)

In the message you can send an object that holds any data you would like to send back and forth between the view models.

I highly recomend using a framework when working with mvvm it makes like much easier. [MVVM Framework Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use) is a link to an answer that goes through a comparison of some of the major frameworks.

Comment: +1. I've seen pretty impressive things done with messaging (things like animation and whatnot), so the performance should be good.

Comment: So, you say that I need to implement a whole paradigm to get a basic functionality like a select category items form category list ? Or I need to utilize a whole framework to get it working ?

Comment: The messaging and framework are for cross view model communication or for communication from view to view model not for simple binding.

In MVVM Light you can take just the parts you would like to use and implement them but using a messaging paradigm that's already created for you makes a lot of sence instead of creating your own publisher/subscriber model and implementing that. You don't need to implement the entire framework if you don't want to, however, you will likely save a lot of time by implementing a framework

Comment: For what I understand - Framework is a way to go for something more sophisticated. But in my opinion, using it in my scenario is like taking a battle tank for killing an ant ;) . I will take a closer look at MVVM Light framework, it seems powerfull - thanks for a tip